# Criterion for a function being a representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I know that $\rho: G\rightarrow GL(V)$ is a representation of the group $G$ iff $\rho$ is a homomorphism of groups. But, my professor use to do something shorter to prove that some function is or not a representation. That is the following:

Given a group $G$ with presentation (for example) $<a,b |~~ a^2=b^2=(ab)^2=1>$, to prove that some $\rho$ is a representation of $G$ we just need to verify that $\rho$ "satisfies the relations of the generators", i.e, that $\rho(a)^2=\rho(b)^2=\rho(ab)^2=1$(this *one* is the identical operator in $V$). **And what I don't get is why this is valid**.

Is it trivial that this implies that $\rho$ is a group homomorphism??

Comment: You can have a function $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ such that $\rho(a)$ and $\rho(b)$ satisfy the same relations as $a$ and $b$ but isn't a homomorphism. However, if you're in the process of *making* a homomorphism, all you have to do is pick what $\rho(a)$ and $\rho(b)$ are and that they satisfy the defining relations that $a$ and $b$ satisfy, and then that automatically determines what $\rho(g)$ needs to be for all other $g\in G$ in order for $\rho$ to be a homomorphism, and so $\rho$ is "constructed" in this manner. Does that make sense?

Comment: @anon that helped me clarifying my ideas, thanks a lot! My theacher use to do exercises like this: given some $\rho:G\rightarrow GL_n(F)$ with the values of $\rho$ in the generators of $G$, then to proove that this $\rho$ is a representation of the group he only prooved that $\rho$ satisfies the generators relations... I think that this isn't too clear, right? It would have to be said that we are kind of presuming some "multiplicative structure", or that we are in fact constructing (instead of proving) a representation... Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

$G$ is the quotient of the free group $F$ on letters $a$ and $b$ by the smallest normal subgroup $N$ containing $a^2$, $b^2$ and $(ab)^2$.

Given any group $H$, and two elements $h_1$ and $h_2$, there is a unique
homomorphism $\phi:F\to H$ with $\phi(a)=h_1$ and $\phi(b)=h_2$. 
In your example, $H=GL(V)$. If $h_1^2=h_2^2=(h_1h_2)^2=e$ then $a^2$, $b^2$ and $(ab)^2$ are in the kernel $K$ of $\phi$. This implies that $N\le K$ and so $\phi$ factors through $F/N=G$.

Comment: Why this implies that his metod is correct? I can't see it